# UTF8 characters not displayed in browsers both Firefox and Google Chrome

Tags: linux, browser, utf-8

I use Linux Debian and everything used to work fine.

After upgrading to the newer 'bullseye' distribution I decided to compile my own kernel. All went well and I thought everything was working until this started to happen.

When I try to browse a news website from Sri Lanka what I see is shown below in the attached image. Instead of utf8 it is displaying this as shown in the image below. This happens in both Firefox and Google Chrome. What should I do to resolve this please?

This is what I see in the browser:

[image: This is what I see in the browser]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Looks like you are missing a font?

Comment: @DavidPostill Thanks, this fixed it.
aruna@debian:~$ sudo apt-get install fonts-lklug-sinhala ibus im-config ibus-m17n m17n-db